# Get 60 error with curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s

Tags: bash, curl, ssl, rvm

I can't seem to figure out how to run

```
 curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
```

And not get an error. I have a mac osx mavericks and the error I get is this:

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

I tried using --insecure and I tried --cacert to the .pem file here:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

I cant seem to install certutil. I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update your system and your system SSL certificates, use this answer for more details on updating certificates => https://stackoverflow.com/a/19151697/497756

Comment: I appreciate it.  i tried these commands                 `cert_file=$(ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE')`                               and                                                          `security find-certificate -a -p > "$cert_file"`                  but on the second command I got                                    `-bash: /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Permission denied`       so I can't seem to get past this point

Comment: you can use `cert_file=/tmp/cert.pem` and then `sudo cp /tmp/cert.pem /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem`

Comment: After performing those two commands I get `cp: /tmp/cert.pem: No such file or directory`. Is there an issue with the certificate not being created?

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to mix it with the other code, first set cert to temp path, then generate it and finally `sudo cp` it to proper path

Comment: @mpapis : can you provide more insight to your last comment

Comment: run `echo insecure > ~/.curlrc`, install rvm, run `sed -i'' -e '/insecure/ d' ~/.rvmrc` and follow instructions in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19151697/497756