# CURL fails to load https resources; NSS error -8181

Tags: curl, https

I've been trying to configure fresh dedicated server, when found a strange behavior of curl on CentOS 6 (and 7):

```
curl "https://google.com"
```

returns

```
curl (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
```

Seems like curl does not know anything about CA installed on current system.

```
# curl https://google.com --verbose
* About to connect() to google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 172.217.25.174... connected
* Connected to google.com (172.217.25.174) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Remote Certificate has expired.
* NSS error -8181
* Closing connection #0
* Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

`--insecure` is not good for me.

I've tried to:

- reinstall `ca-certificates`,
- extract certificates via `update-ca-trust extract`
- download third-party ca certificate
- even set a `--cacert` option to curl execution directly

but it does not help me.

First thought - okay, fresh OS could not has actual version of certificates, but what if I do `yum update -y`? Should be actual, shouldn't it?

I've checked previously asked questions like this [get-60-error-with-curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915693/get-60-error-with-curl-l-https-get-rvm-io-bash-s) and many others.

Comment: By the way, NSS Error -8181 is indeed that the remote certificate has expired (https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ref/ssl/sslerr.html#:~:text=%2D8181 ) - or in your case, not valid yet.  I guess from an SSL perspective it makes sense to treat both the same, but from an end user's perspective, it is often very worth knowing if a cert seems to be from the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one thing that figured me out was that line - `* Remote Certificate has expired.` from a verbose response from curl execution.

How google's certificate could be in expired state? What time is right now?

Oops:

```
# date
Friday, 10 May 2015 12:35:21 -0400
```

But now is 11/30/2017.

Okay,

```
sudo yum install ntp ntpdate -y
```

then you have to check `/etc/ntpd.conf`, if it not present:

```
sudo su
echo "server 0.pool.ntp.org" > /etc/ntpd.conf && service ntpd start
```

And check:

```
# date
Thursday, 30 November 2017 14:03:35 +0000
```

Don't forget to set localtime, for example UTC time:

```
sudo mv /etc/localtime /tmp/localtime.bak
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

P.S. More info about ntp configuration you could get [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-understanding_the_ntpd_configuration_file)