# Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ssl, github

I'm getting this error when I run `bundle install`:

```
Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely 
your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using 
SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

However, it is only happening to one of my projects, and seems to be happening to only me.  Also, I can get around it by running `bundle update`, where I don't get that error, and I can get up a running after that.

Is there something that isn't tracked in the project (that is only on my machine) that I have misconfigured?

Comment: Try this: ```gem update --system``` and then if you are on a MAC try this: ```rvm osx-ssl-certs update```

Comment: Also check that your system has the correct date/time. (For example, if it's a virtual machine, it could lose the time if you hibernate the host.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had this problem on Mac OS X Yosemite with ruby 2.3.1.
I fixed the problem by downloading http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem to 
`/usr/local/etc/openssl/`

and adding this line `export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cacert.pem` to `.bash_profile`

Credit to [Can't run Ruby 2.2.3 with RVM on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353917/cant-run-ruby-2-2-3-with-rvm-on-osx/32363597#32363597) but it was hard to google the right answer, so added to this page.

Comment: In case it is not obvious to Zsh users, add the export line to .zshrc

Comment: Updated this as a better answer due to upvotes (and my solution was 5 years old)

Comment: This solution worked for me too. For Mac OSX BigSur, Ruby 2.6.4 and RVM 1.29.7 (1.29.7)

Answer (score 12):

The solution for me on OS X 10.9.5 was to `sudo rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`.

Source: http://jacopretorius.net/2013/10/could-not-verify-the-ssl-certificate-for-rubygems.html

Answer (score 5):

Running `gem update --system` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

For linux users, simply install the package: `ca-certificates`

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, using `rbenv` on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Answer (score 2):

Since I am using `rbenv` instead of `rvm`, I wasn't able to do most of the solutions online.

I was able to fix the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling `openssl`

All is well, but I am not exactly sure why.

Comment: here is also a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o

Comment: dont try this, man. most of my Dependant packages got removed as result.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading openssl should fix the issue.(if it's MacOSX)

```
brew upgrade openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

Using OSX `10.14.6` and Rails 6 this worked for me:

`rvm osx-ssl-certs update`

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this method will be useful

1.Switch source to `https://gems.ruby-china.org/`

```
$ gem sources --add https://gems.ruby-china.org/ --remove https://rubygems.org/
```

2.Check current source

```
$ gem sources -l

*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://gems.ruby-china.org
```

3.Mirror gem source

```
$ bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org https://gems.ruby-china.org
```

Through these methods, you will not need to change `Gemfile souce`.

Hope this method will be useful for you.