# Can't run Ruby 2.2.3 with RVM on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

I've got two MacBooks (one on Mavericks, the other on Yosemite) and the same thing happens on both.
After installing Ruby 2.2.3 with RVM, I get the following error:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (Faraday::SSLError)
```

I've tried searching for a solution online, but nothing seems to work. Most of the people having this issues are running Windows machines.

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
```

Switching back to 2.2.2 works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you read this article? https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Comment: Yes, I already have a AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem in my .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ssl_certs folder

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Downloading http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and adding

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=PATH_TO_THe_DOWNLOADED_FILE/cacert.pem
```

to the .bash_profile/.zshrc partially fixed the issue, because it throws the following error on my system:

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError: Unable to verify certificate, please set `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_path] = path_to_certs`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = path_to_certs`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_file] = path_to_file`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = path_to_file`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_callback] = callback` (see OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#verify_callback), or `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false` (less secure).
```

Setting Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] to false in a Rails initializer (only on development/test envs) makes it work.

**Update:** Reinstalling 2.2.3 from source got rid of all my problems.

```
rvm remove 2.2.3
rvm install 2.2.3 --disable-binary
```

Comment: Ditto on reinstalling and disabling binary solving these problems.

Comment: Why does disabling binary fix it?

Comment: @Taysky the reason disabling the binary works is that the binaries being used by RVM are linking to /etc/openssl for the certs dir and the cert file, which is mostly likely not where they are most peoples systems. You can of course just set the path using the environmental variables noted. However some people would rather just compile ruby by hand and avoid that.

Comment: @geekbri - ah ok. Thanks!

Comment: can't you just `rvm reinstall 2.2.3 --disable-binary`? No idea if that will work 100%, though.

Comment: That works for me. Although there is still SSL warnings but the bundler works. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't help myself otherwise than with `brew install openssl` on El Capitan. I've tried everything like updating certs using RVM, replacing SSL certs from haxx.se, or reinstalling ruby. Nothing else worked.