# Error" Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://code.stripe.com/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am getting the following error message while trying to install stripe. Is there any work around for this issue? 
I was following a tutorial on stripe.

```
"Fetching source index from https://code.stripe.com/
 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
 Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://code.stripe.com/.
 There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
 likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
 information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without
 using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'."
```

Comment: This is common on older systems with outdated certificate bundles. Updating your certificate bundle will fix the problem. Visit the link in the message for instructions on how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)