# Install rails in windows machine: error fetching http://rubygems.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to install rails on windows7. Rails not getting installed
gem sources --add http://rubygems.org commands throws error like Error fetching http://rubygems.org timed out http://API.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz

Can anyone help me resolve this.

Comment: Are you sure with what you wrote above? `gem sources --add http://rubygdms.org` or just typo? If it's typo correct it.

Comment: It's just typo error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gem install cannot download from rubygems.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260919/gem-install-cannot-download-from-rubygems-org)

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by updating your `rubygems` to latest version.

`gem update --system`

Comment: I'm creating new rails app..rails itself not getting installed..is there any network issue?

Comment: @Sidduh do mention the steps you are using to setup new application

Comment: I'm setting up rails application in windows 7 and steps followed are. 1. Installed latest Ruby 2.5 2.edit .gemrc and added :sources: ["http://rubygems.org"].    3.gem install rails

Comment: Rails application is not setup yet..how can I edit gemfile .. gem install rails command throwing error

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this error by adding http://rubygejs.org/ to .gemrc.