# rubygem install SSL error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Anytime I try to install any gem of late I get this kind of error message for example:

> could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why: unable to
>   download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSl_connects returned=1
>   eerno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify
>   failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

[This ticket](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/665) contains several solutions. You may want to

1. Try to upgrade your local RubyGems setup

   ```
   $ gem update --system
   ```
2. If you use RVM, upgrade RVM and [upgrade the certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o).

Here's a [debugging tool](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/07/ruby-openssl/).