# Update bash error for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ssl, ssl-certificate

When I try to start a new project - my command I'm using is:

```
rails new testproject
```

But when it tries to install the bundle I end up with the error message:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed <https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2.gem>
An error occured while installing rake <10.4.2>, and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2' ' succeeds before bundling.
```

So then I try to install that rake version, using

```
gem install rake -v 10.4.2
```

and I get the same SSL read server certificate error.

Now I've tried to figure out how to fix this. From what I can tell, I need to update my Bash version, but that's impossible for me - it just tells me what bash version I have when I give it the command

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

found on https://rvm.io/rvm/install.

How do I fix this issue and how do I get an actual working version of RoR on my computer without having to do everything manually? Almost all the other places I've been to eventually point back to railsinstaller.org, and that does me no good.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/19151697/429758

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with the certificates. You could try to fetch the packages from hhtp instead using something like:

```
sudo gem sources -r https://rubygems.org
sudo gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)