# Ruby ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'premailer'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i get only this error, when i try to install premailer...

```
C:\..mypath..\newsletter> gem install premailer
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'premailer' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

thats my ruby version i have installed

```
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x64-mingw32]
```

anyone have an idea how to fix that error?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o) and you should [look this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o/27298259#27298259)

Comment: ok i found the solution there :)

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88