# Errors beginning with Ruby on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following error. Could you please let me know how to solve them?
Many thanks in advance.

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3   read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2.gem) An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.

C:\Sites\firstTest>gem install rake -v '10.4.2'ERROR:  While executing gem... (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError) U+00E9 to IBM866 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM866
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to manually upgrade your rubygems version as explained here: [unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29638157/1978840)