# SSL certificate verify failed when installing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I set up Rails project and database on Windows and some gems are missing. When trying to install them I get the following error:

```
    Following gems were not installed:
    bundler:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
               Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect
    returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server 
    certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I tried

> https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

and

> [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o/27298259#27298259)

but non of this worked.
Any ideas?

Comment: you could just switch to `http` rather than `https`. I have noticed that doing this and then switching back sometimes resolves the issue.

Comment: unfortunately didnt work

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround, you can simply change `source 'https://rubygems.org'` in your gemfile to `source http://rubygems.org`. Then run `bundle`.

I've had the exact same problem before, and after that, I was able to install my gems.

For a better solution, run `gem update --system`

Comment: I tried it few times, but it is not working. I think it can be like that, because https://gems.github.com/ sie is down and it is not able to get gems.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows with PowerShell installed

Installing Windows PowerShell

Paste this 1line code in command console: (WIN + R, cmd)

```
powershell -Command "& {$fname='cacert.pem'; $outpath=\"$($(Get-ChildItem Env:USERPROFILE).Value)/$fname\"; Invoke-WebRequest http://curl.haxx.se/ca/$fname -OutFile \"$outpath\"; [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('SSL_CERT_FILE', \"$outpath\", 'User')}"
```

Script will do:

1. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Save it as `%USERPROFILE%/cacert.pem ( C:\Users\__you__\cacert.pem)`
3. Set persistent environment variable for current user `SSL_CERT_FILE` as `%USERPROFILE%/cacert.pem`

After this try to install the gem