# Problems with rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have installed rails from railsinstaller.org and i tried to run a

```
Rails new myrubyblog
```

and after the gems were created it told me

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read sever certificate B: certificate Verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n-0.7.0.gem)

An error occurred while installing i18n (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 'gem install i18n -v '0.7.0''succeeds before bundling.
```

After that occured i then ran:

```
gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'
```

Then i ran

```
Rails new my
```

and the same thing occurred but instead it told me to run:

```
gem install json -v '1.8.3'
```

I don't know what else to do now could someone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)

Comment: Means your SSL certificate isn't allowing you to connect to RubyGems. Simplest hack is to use `source http://rubygems.org` in your `Gemfile` ;)