# issue ssl in ruby on rails in ubuntu 15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ssl, rvm

I am a novice in Linux and Ruby and Ruby on Rails .
I 've installed rvm and Ruby .
Now to install Ruby on Rails Len problems.

```
moh@ubuntu:~$ gem install rails --no-ri 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.2.5.1.gemspec.rz)
```

Why not install what I should do؟

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o

Comment: I was there for Mac OS and Windows to Ubuntu did not please help

Comment: Please, see once again, there is information for rvm users too.