# Unable to successfully install Susy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phpstorm, susy

I'm using PhpStorm 10. I attempted to install Susy 2.2.12 and received the following error:

```
Successfully installed susy-2.2.12 Parsing documentation for susy-2.2.12  
Done installing documentation for susy after 0 seconds  
WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certifica te verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz) 
1 gem installed
```

When I verify if susy installed, I see that it didn't. I attempted to install using the command line in PhpStorm and with the node.js command prompt, where I get the same error. I did a gem cleanup and that didn't help.

I'm using Windows 8.1.

I find this issue confusing. The suggested answer related to SSL issues when ruby on rails didn't install. My issue is specific to susy. I was quickly lost with how to correct the certificate issue. Can some one dumb down this issue for me?

My question: What do I need to do to correct the issue with certificate verify failed? I'm assuming this is blocking me from a successful install.I'm a newbie at this and new simplified help.

Comment: What is your question? [2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)