# Certificate issue while trying to install MySQL gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am getting the below error while trying to install MySQL gem.

> Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

What does it mean? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I hope your have rvm. I updated the certificates. first

```
rvm get stable
```

then update the certificates

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

or Alternatively you can also do

```
rvm rubygems latest
```

there are further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o) if this did not helped.