# Unable to install gems due to certificate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, carrierwave

When trying to install gems this error appears

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'carrierwave' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Can't find the reason why

Comment: Norepro here, you probably have an SSL error on your client, or someone (possibly your employer) is trying to filter/MITM your SSL connections.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)

Comment: Nope, tried that solution, couldn't solve it =/

Answer (score 0):

Try...

1. Download the cacert.pem: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Copy the file to the certs directory(ssl_certs) of you ruby installation. Try to find it with windows search