# gem install sass error

Tags: ruby, sass

I am trying to install sass and I tried ruby installer. I am getting the error as follow.Please anyone help.

```
C:\Ruby23-x64>gem install sass
```

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
>                 Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Which version of ruby you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gem install` by default uses https://rubygems.org/ as it's source for gems, but you can specify the source using `--source` option and give a non-SSL source to install like following:

```
gem install sass --source http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: After installing and watching for the scss file i get an error

Comment: As par SO guidelines, you can ask a fresh question, with details of the error.

Comment: This is quite bad and dangerous advice! Rubygems uses the secure https transport by default for a reason, namely to ensure that the downloaded gems are not tampered with on the way from rubygems.org to the client. A much better advice would be to fix the certificates on the client.

Comment: if the above solution doesn't work as expected, sometimes updating to the latest ruby package does fix it.