# rubygem timeout on bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, timeout, rvm

I am getting a timeout error trying to update my gems. I would prefer not to have to change to unsecured paths.

I can download the gems individually from rubygems using my browser - but `gem update` and `rvm gemset update` both fail with the following error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
>       timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

When I run bundle update - I run into individual gems timing out (hence knowing I can download and install them individually), as an example:

> Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: timed out
>   (https://rubygems.org/gems/ffi-1.9.23.gem)
>   An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.23), and Bundler cannot
>   continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.23'` succeeds before bundling.

I have followed these posts:

1. [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)
2. https://rubygems.org/pages/download#formats

Comment: not helpful - but I ended up having my whole environment reset. probably not the best solution.

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800432/gem-cannot-access-rubygems-org

Answer (score 4):

I got it solved by simple switching by wifi on/off on my Macbook Pro with OSx Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

the rubygems host server sometimes have problems dealing with ipv6.

Basically i have changed my preference from ipv6 to ipv4 in windows 10. That must help for other systems to.

For WINDOWS you'll do as follows:

1. check your prefixpolicies:

   - run

     ```
     netsh insterface ipv6 show prefixpolicies
     ```
   - the output should be something like this:

     ```
     Precedence label Prefix

     ----------  -----  --------------------------------

     50      0  ::1/128
     40      1  ::/0        
     30      2  2002::/16
     20      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
     ```

The higher the number of precedence, higher the priority.

So as you see, ipv6 ::/0 is right next to the localhost as the second priority.

2. Let's put ipv4 in a higher preference.

   - run:

     ```
     netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicies ::ffff:0:0/96 46 4
     ```

After running this comand, try looking the prefixpolicies again.

You will find ipv4 in a higher precedence now, with 46 beeing higher than 40 from ipv6.

3. Now try reaching for the rubygem host running any "gem" command, you will probably be very pleased.