# error when trying to install ruby gem gosu

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Unable to install gosu ruby gem.  When I try to run

```
gem install gosu
```

it throws this error:

```
Could not find a valid gem 'gosu' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 
read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version 
(https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

How can I install this gem?

Comment: Please tell us which versions of Ruby (`ruby -v`) and RubyGems (`gem -v`) you're using

Comment: First [see this as you may need to use RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)
You'll need to refer to the gem wiki and depending on your OS there should be instructions to install required libraries.  https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki