# rails server won't run?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I've installed Ruby and Rails, and for the most part it's installed. However, when I try to create an app to see if all the installations work, the rails server won't run. It goes something like this:

- I created a new rails app file, it's shown in my C: directory so that's a success
- but the last line at the installation said this:

```
bundle install
The latest bundler is 2.3.10, but you are currently running 1.15.3.
To update, run `gem install bundler`
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/"
```

- I tried the

```
gem install bundler
```

next, but I got this error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

- also when I tried,

```
rails s
```

I got this result:

```
Usage:
rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
-r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                       # Default: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe
-m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
-d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                       # Default: sqlite3
    [--skip-yarn], [--no-skip-yarn]                    # Don't use Yarn for managing JavaScript dependencies
    [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
-G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
    [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
-M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]  # Skip Action Mailer files
-O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
-P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                    # Skip Puma related files
-C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]    # Skip Action Cable files
-S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
    [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
    [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
    [--skip-coffee], [--no-skip-coffee]                # Don't use CoffeeScript
-J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
    [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
-T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                    # Skip test files
    [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]      # Skip system test files
    [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
    [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
    [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
    [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
    [--api], [--no-api]                                # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps
-B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
    [--webpack=WEBPACK]                                # Preconfigure for app-like JavaScript with Webpack (options: react/vue/angular)

Runtime options:
-f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
-p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
-q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
-s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
-h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
-v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
defaults values shown above in this help message.

    Example:rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

I have tried to install bundler, update bundler, update system... none of that worked. I've also tried the `cacert.pem` file for certification (according to one of the tutorial articles I found), but it's still doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 10, ruby 2.3.3p222 and Rails 5.1.3. With this, do I need to reinstall Ruby and Rails? Is there something missing in my installation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"I've tried the `cacert.pem` file for certification, but it's still doesn't work"*, but you may find this official FAQ troubleshooting guide helpful: https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#updating-ca-certificates

Comment: Firstly, please check if you running `rails s` from correct directory

if issue still persist, checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o

Comment: you are not in the root of you application directory, running rails outside of a rails application will present you with the issues you are seeing, I would suggest you use rvm to manage your gemsets. it will make your life a whole lot less complicated